# cross-compiling x264 for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I'm novice in cross-compiling and just started to cross-compile packages on my linux machine (amd64) for host (NAS) with ARMv5 (linux kernel 2.6.31.8). I installed crosstool-ng and with it created toolchain for compilation for ARM. According to some tutorials online I succeeded to compile x264 package. But now when I try to run it, I was given the following error message

```
./x264: /lib/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./x264)
```

Ok now I see that I need libm library but what it is and how to compile x264 with it?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message: the version of x264 you built requires version of glibc 2.15. The Glibc is built as part of your cross compilation toolchain (through crosstool-ng).

You need to build a new toolchain with the same version of glibc found on your NAS root filesystem (or compatible).

(edited after @NotLikeThat comment)

Comment: I think you may have misread the question; that's a runtime error from the dynamic loader, not a build error. OP _has_ built x264 against glibc 2.15 (or higher) from the cross-toolchain, and _that's the problem_, since there apparently isn't a new-enough version available on the target system.

Comment: Now I see, it's very old linux system and there's glibc v2.8. I will have to build new toolchain with this glibc. We'll see how it will go.

Comment: @Notlikethat you are correct I was mislead by the question, the error is indeed caused at runtime.

Comment: @sbrbot A possibly simpler alternative would be to configure (or hack up) the x264 build process to add the `--sysroot` option pointing at a copy of your real target filesystem, rather than rebuilding the whole toolchain for the sake of changing its own default sysroot.